# Custom UIButton rounder corners become squared on highlight?

Tags: ios, xcode, button

I have the following code for a custom UIButton:

```
btnLogin.layer.cornerRadius = 10;

[btnLogin setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bluetint.png"]]];
[btnLogin setAlpha:1];
[btnLogin setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnLogin setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reallybluetint.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[btnLogin setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"reallybluetint.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

When I highlight the button it becomes squared even though it has rounded corners in the Normal state.

Any ideas?

Comment: Using the uicontrolstate creates a default button when highlighted. Therefore square corners. If you like I can show you how to create your button with quarts core.

Answer (score 7):

Try with this code it will work,

```
btnLogin.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
[btnLogin setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Also I have had a similar problem make sure that the button in Interface builder is set to custom, because if it is not you will see the rounded corners.

Also something useful I found when working with images was UIEdgeInsets. So I might do a programmatic custom button like this.

```
UIButton * customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[customButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"customerImage.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(1, 4, 2, 4)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The but with any image you can use resizableImageWithCapInsets. I would recommend reading up on this to make sure that you can configure it properly, but even if it doesn't help you know it could help you later.

[Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Just control F for resizable

Hope this helps ^_^

p.s. The rounded corners will work however if you try this and it doesn't work make sure you have imported Quartzcore. I often forget this step and become angst when until I can figure it out. Anyway good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift**:

```
import UIKit

class CustomUIButtonForUIToolbar: UIButton {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        super.drawRect(rect)
        ...
        self.clipsToBounds = true
    }

}
```